# iOS: About CF object and objective-c object retain count

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have tested 3 codes below under **ARC**:

1、readStream.retainCount = 2;

```
       @property(nonatomic, strong) NSInputStream *readStream;

        CFReadStreamRef ref = CFReadStreamCreateForHTTPRequest(kCFAllocatorDefault, request);
        [self setReadStream:(__bridge NSInputStream *)(ref)];
        CFRelease(ref);
```

2、readStream.retainCount = 3;

```
        [self setReadStream:（__bridge NSInputStream *）(CFReadStreamCreateForHTTPRequest(kCFAllocatorDefault, request))];
```

3、readStream.retainCount = 3;

```
[self setReadStream:CFBridgingRelease(CFReadStreamCreateForHTTPRequest(kCFAllocatorDefault, request))];
```

My question is: Why 1 is different from 2&3 ? Which usage is correct ? And is the *readStream* should be **strong** property?

Comment: 2 & 3 are the same? or is it a copy paste error?

Comment: `retainCount` is nearly useless under MRC, and even moreso under ARC.

Comment: @Kevin is right. Never even look at the retain count. Just do memory management properly. Use the Static Analyzer to confirm.

Comment: @Merlevede yeah, sorry for that. I have corrected that copy error:)

Comment: @ZhaoRocky With the correction, in your second example you would need to use CFRelease.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFDesignConcepts/Articles/tollFreeBridgedTypes.html):

> __bridge transfers a pointer between Objective-C and Core Foundation with no transfer of ownership.
>
> __bridge_transfer or CFBridgingRelease moves a non-Objective-C pointer to Objective-C and also transfers ownership to ARC.

This means that both approaches are valid. Basically what it says is that if you use `CFBridgingRelease` you should not use `CFRelease` because you transfer the ownership, that's why you see an increase in the retainCount, although, as 'Kevin' pointed out, in ARC that's meaningless.

Regarding the second question, your `readStream` variable can be strong or not. There's no special consideration here.

Comment: #1 and #3 are both correct. #2 leaks because it retains without releasing.